# Create new ProjectTemplate and not found into project template list

Tags: templates, visual-studio-2019

Templates created do not appear in the template list for new projects

I created a simple c # project and exported it as a template.
* the zip is pushed into Visual Studio 2019 \ Templates \ ProjectTemplates
* and in Visual Studio 2019 \ My Exported Templates

But I can not find in the visual studio window when creating a new project

[image: list template]

I can not use a created template, which does not contain any changes to the .vstemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command allowed me to refresh the templates:

> devenv /installvstemplates

it is no longer documented on vs2019, it was used in the previous version. But it still seems to work and essential to update the list of templates

if you want to modify your template and see the effects directly

1. your template which is here

   > Documents\Visual Studio
   >   2019\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Philippe_Project
2. Delete Philippe_Project.zip into parent dir
3. You can modify files into dir